# Best way to size an element to the size of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using an old CSS trick to get a semi-transparent background for some content, without the content appearing semi-transparent. Here is the HMTL:

```
<div id="frame">
    <div id="opacityFrame">
    </div>
    <div id="contentFrame">
        <div>
            <!-- Main Site Content Here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
#frame
{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

#opacityFrame
{
    background: #00ff00;
    opacity: .15;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#contentFrame
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

My problem is that because `#frame` is position: relative, it's height does not dynamically expand with its content. Both `#opacityFrame` and `#contentFrame` are set to 100% height and width and they appropriately expand to fill `#frame` which is great. The issue is that I need `#frame`'s height to grow with the contents of the child `DIV` of `#contentFrame` because that `DIV`'s height dynamically adjusts with the content placed in it.

I ended up having to create a jQuery function:

```
function resizeFrame()
{
    $('#frame').height($('#contentFrame > div').height());
}
```

NOTE: The reason there is a child `DIV` of `#contentFrame` is because `#contentFrame`'s height always reads as zero for some weird reason. I'm assuming it has to do with its `position` being `absolute`.

This code works great and accurately resizes `#frame`'s height to the height of the child `DIV` of `#contentFrame`. However, I do a lot of ajax that changes the content within that `DIV`. One solution would be to call `resizeFrame()` with EVERY ajax event but it just seems so tedious. Is there an event or something I can tie to that would execute this function without my explicitly having to call it? I tried the following events but they didn't seem to work; maybe I did them wrong.

- `$('#subFrame > div').resize()`
- `$('#subFrame > div').change()`

Neither of these seemed to fire when the contents of the child `DIV` were modified. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way? I do not want to use transparent images for the background.

Comment: 'frame' is also a name of a tag, so I'd suggest not using that term as a class to avoid confusion in the CSS file.

Comment: Frame is not a class, it is just an ID, made plainly obvious by the `#`.

Comment: It's obvious to you the author, but not necessarily obvious to the person that has to update the site in 6 months. In general, it's just a good rule of thumb to not use tag names for class and ID names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking position: absolute off of the contentFrame but leaving it on the opacityFrame. That should cause it's parent to resize, and the opacityFrame to still overlay everything.

Comment: I think I tried this but can't remember. I'll test it now and see what happens.

Comment: Ah yes I did try this, `#opacityFrame` goes over the top of the `#contentFrame` and no amount of `z-index` adjustments will fix it because they don't have the same `position` rule. Also note that putting `#contentFrame` inside `#opacityFrame` causes `#contentFrame` to suffer from the same `opacity` rule.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/28FvM/6/ z-index does not apply to non-positioned elements. all you have to do is give it a position: relative; with no offset.

Answer (score -1):

do you have to use opacity? If it's a solid color, consider RGBA or if it's not solid, consider a semi-transparent PNG. That way you can nest them.

Comment: I specifically stated I did not want to use images to achieve this. And yes, I need opacity. See http://www.CodeTunnel.com for actual implementation.